# Use Javascript Date into Salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery, date

I have a visualforce that uses Remote Action to do requests and send a date as parameter. 
There is a field date on my visualforce page, it'is an input text, and I need to use it in Apex Code as a Date.

Is there any method in SfdcCore DateUtil that should I use? Or another method to do  independently of user location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Date methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm).

`Date.parse(someDate)`

Comment: Really, I was so worried about convert before sending to apex that I forgot that. Thank you!